# Can't select "Build Solution"

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssas, data-cube

I am getting trouble to use `Build solution` in Visual Studio.

I was building data cube and I needed to use `Build solution` to finalize  my project.

However, I couldn't find `Build solution` from the Build menu.

For example ....

http://cfile7.uf.tistory.com/image/18493D524E2CF5A31F8B61

It should be like this then I can choose build solution option

However, when I tried on my laptop...

http://cfile8.uf.tistory.com/image/16493D524E2CF5A21E9D27

I was unable to find these options...

I am not really sure about my mistakes....

My data was built by SQL Server 2008 R2 and I was using Visual Studio (which came with SQL Server)

Does anybody know solution to this problem?

Comment: It's Visual St**U**dio - with a "U" in the middle there.....

Answer (score 1):

From the second screenshot that you posted, it looks like you don't have a solution open, just the project that was contained in the solution.  A Visual Studio solution file is usually a .sln file, and if you open it up in Notepad you'll see that it's just an XML file which describes project(s) it contains (the actual project files are different, the solution just makes reference to the project filenames).  Make sure you get the .sln file to your laptop and open that, not the project file.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the solution or Project node which is on the Solution-Explorer. There should be Build menu item.

Or may be the Visual Studio coming with SQL 2008 R2 doesn't have that functionality?